# Are there any other, mathematical methods$?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Consider $(1+x)^{2n}+(1+2x+x^2)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{2n}a_rx^r,n\in\mathbb{N}.$ If $\sum_{r=0}^{2n}a_r=f(n)$ then find the value of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f(n)}$

By some solving, one can easily see that we have to find the value of $$\frac{1}{2\left(\binom{2}{0}+\binom{2}{1}+\binom{2}{2}\right)}+\frac{1}{2\left(\binom{4}{0}+\binom{4}{1}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{4}{3}+\binom{4}{4}\right)}+\frac{1}{2\left(\binom{6}{0}+\binom{6}{1}+\binom{6}{2}+\binom{6}{3}+\binom{6}{4}+\binom{6}{5}+\binom{6}{6}\right)}+\cdots$$
Since the summation is till infinity so all terms but first contribute very less to the sum, so they can be ignored. This means that the value of the infinite summation is the value of the first term i.e. $\frac16$

My question is, that whether this is a correct approach or not. The answer given is indeed $\frac16.$ What I think that this method is not mathematical. Can anyone provide me with a more mathematical method involving maybe some telescopics.

Comment: The answer to your question is "no" (or maybe "no of course not").  You might start with the fact that the first term of the sum is not equal to $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: @JBL but $\frac{1}{2\left(\binom{2}{0}+\binom{2}{1}+\binom{2}{2}\right)}=\frac16$

Comment: It is actually $\frac18$ if I am not doing anything wrong.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @KamalSaleh oh damn

Comment: This question is great though so I will upvote it. There was a very simple mistake that doesn't affect the OP as a whole.

Comment: @KamalSaleh thanks...actually now I found the correct way to solve it...using  infinite geometric progession...should I include that method?

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Include everything you tried if you can :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I think the question is solved (from the comments), but since the OP did not post their solution, I will post mine:

$$(x+1)^{2n}+(x^2+2x+1)^n = 2(x+1)^{2n}$$By the binomial theorem, this is just:
$$2\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{r}x^r = \sum_{r=0}^{2n}2\binom{2n}{r}x^r$$
Therefore, $$f(n) = \sum_{r=0}^{2n}a_r = \sum_{r=0}^{2n}2\binom{2n}{r} = 2\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{r} = 2\cdot2^{2n} = 2^{2n+1}$$

Now, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f(n)}$ is a simple geometric series with first term $1/8$ and common ratio $1/4$. Since $|1/4|<1$, we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{f(n)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} = \frac{1/8}{1-\frac 14}$$
which gives the required answer $\boxed{1/6}$.